# Help identifying this dark color moss

Tags: identification, moss, venus-fly-trap

I got the following type of moss and I would like to find out its exact name and as bonus a recommendation if this is appropriate for the Venus flytrap (*Dionaea muscipula*):

[image]

Related question on [Help identifying this light color moss](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/37352/help-identifying-this-light-color-moss).

Comment: "exact name" with such photos? Mosses identification is difficult. For me, these are some Sphagnum like mosses (which should be ok for Venus-Flytrap), but I'm far for an expert.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the pictures are good quality if you zoom them. But anyway, could you point me to some page with high-quality pictures of the main types of moss?, do you know of any such resource?.

Comment: There are many parallel evolution. Usually books have hand made diagrams. Important characters are form of leaflets, how are the veins. But for full determination, you need a microscope.  My "identification" is given by colours and form: it seems mosses in water. But I'm not an expert, maybe some other type of mosses are similar.

Comment: Jaime, thanks for splitting them up. Now you have two for getting rep and answers!

Comment: Use this academic site to identify the moss, select the larget images when you look at the results pages:  http://www.discoverlife.org/mp/20q?guide=Mosses_USID