# Help identifying this light color moss

Tags: identification, moss

I got the following type of moss and I would like to find out its exact name and as bonus a recommendation if this is appropriate for the Venus flytrap (*Dionaea muscipula*):

[image]

Related question on [Help identifying this dark color moss](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/37345/help-identifying-this-dark-color-moss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is [peat moss (sphagnum)](https://www.tnnursery.net/spaghnum-moss-for-sale/) that had been submerged under water and it loses all its color and eventually dies when it's completely submerged.

Answer (score 0):

So I have two guesses and a couple of questions.  This looks like moss in the family of Palustriella or Sphagnum.  Probably you were able to guess those too.  Where did you get it?  If you sourced it outside where do you live?  What kind of environment did you find it in?

As for venus fly trap appropriate question, I don't know what you mean?  Are you mulching it with moss, or using it as growing medium?

If you want to gro this on the surface of the planter with the Venus flytrap, I wouldn't because both these species can grow tall and as a thick carpet.  Used low growing mosses to scape the pots if that is what you're using it for.